# Google Calendar Schduling using Oauth2.0 Works for @gmail.com users only. for non gmail users invitations are not sent

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api

[image]I'm using Google Calendar API using Oauth2.0 to send notifications. I'm using a Gsuite accoun and the invitations are sent for @gmail.com users only. for non gmail users invitations are not sent. When I see the sender calendar, it displays invitees of both gmail and non gmail users. Please suggest

Comment: Can you provide the relevant parts of the code you're using? What kind of notifications are we talking about, emails? What do you mean by `non gmail` users? G Suite accounts? Or non-Google accounts?

Comment: thats the code I'm using. non gmail users mean G Suite user and outlook user.

Comment: For G Suite accounts, most probably you need to change the notification settings on the attendee calendar (on the specific attendee main calendar, select `Other notifications > New events > Email` - not `None`). For non-Google accounts, have you checked that the emails are not in SPAM?